# Does CPU waste time on a java thread thats blocked for IO read/write?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, nonblocking

If a thread is blocked while writing data to IO, does the CPU need to give this thread any time till this IO operation is complete?

If so, why should the CPU relinquish?

If not, is there any thing otherthan "stack per thread" that makes "request per thread" not to perform as good as "non blocking IO with shared threads" under heavy load?

PS: I have read a decent number of SO questions on this topic & I could not find an answer that addressed this specific aspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a thread is blocked while writing data to IO, does the CPU need to
>   give this thread any time till this IO operation is complete?

No, the Operating system will just dequeue a thread that waits to run again and resume it.

> If not, is there any thing otherthan "stack per thread" that makes
>   "request per thread" not to perform as good as "non blocking IO with
>   shared threads" under heavy load?

Dequeuing a waiting thread and resuming it may be cheap for one thread, but it's not cheap when you have thousands of them. don't forget the operating system has to calculate which thread to resume (according to priority), where to resume it (according to the available CPUs and affinity) and the CPU itself would probably have to load the memory used by the thread into the cache lines, which is a real bitch.

Not to mention that the thread that goes to sleep has to flush its data into the RAM itself from the cache lines, and it's a very expensive operation (the cache lines are there for a reason, a big one).

And yeah, the memory consumed by thousands of threads can take up significant amount of memory which slows down the entire system.

Now, it's not like an HTTP server can't perform well with only threads and blocking IO, but since it's so easy today to use asynchronous operations (using futures, async/await, callbacks), that we simply prefer asynchronous IO for servers that actually need speed.

Comment: Is it correct to say
1.In non blocking case, Java just keeps the local variables on the top of the stack & the variables that are accessible from that scope(closures) & discard the whole stack for the current shared thread as soon as the IO operation is issued to the underlying device controller?
2. If so, except the stack, the CPU still needs to bringin/update caches to restore the state to run the callback?
3. In case of blocking IO, by dequeue, CPU will remove the current blocked thread from the threads to be scheduled & will queue this back once it got the interrupt from IO controller

Comment: In the asynchronous case, it's exactly like putting a click-listener on a button. you create an object that encapsulate the data needed for the continuation, and the stack behaves exactly like synchronous code. meaning you launch an asynchronous IO action, and return to the caller, resuming a normal function flow

Comment: The blocked thread will be dequeued & will be scheduled (queued back) only after the interrupt from IO controller is received by CPU that the IO is complete/failed. Is this correct?

Comment: there are many ways to implement asynchronous IO from a programming language perspective. usually, a program has a thread that runs an "event queue" - it's a thread that by definition, sleeps until some event (finished IO, timeout etc) is thrown, it wakes up, dequeues all the relevant event-handlers and either executes them by itself (a la node.js style) or schedules them on a threadpool (a la .NET style)

Comment: Can u also address the thread scheduling in case of blocking IO aswell.
>> No, the Operating system will just dequeue a waiting thread and resume it<<
This statement is a bit confusing. My assumption is "Operating system will just dequeue a waiting thread and resume it when the IO operation is complete". Is this correct?

Comment: Oh wait, I misunderstood your question. the answer is yes, in synchronous IO, the kernel gets an interrupt from the hardware (not necessarily the CPU), and schedules the blocked thread for execution. it's up to the OS scheduler to decide when it'll actually run. my answer above is for async IO

Comment: waiting thread != blocked thread. I meant "a thread that waits for *execution, CPU time*". maybe a "ready thread" is a better term.

Comment: Is it correct to say, in blocking IO, the thread is blocked & will be dequeued by CPU from scheduling till it receives an interrupt from the device controller (microcontroller, not CPU). Once it receives this interrupt, it enqueues the thread for execution. In essence, CPU does not need to waste any cycles on this thread that's doing blocking IO